# How to dynamically get Class in Ruby just like we can call send to trigger a method dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know we can do this:

```
Person.send(:new)
```

But let's say we have this code:

```
class Person
  def self.plural
    'people'
  end
end
```

Is there a way that allows us to do this?

```
klass = Class.get_class('Person')
klass.send(:plural)
# => 'people'
```

What's the name of this concept?

Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby actually allows you get the class object from the argument in the string by using `const_get`. For example

```rb
klass = Object.const_get("Person") # => return Person class
```

Comment: Or use `String#constantize` since this is Rails, then you can handle things like `'A::B::C'.constantize` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like this, for dynamically in rails, script would be something like this:

```rb
# => class_send("Article", :new)

def class_send(class_name, send_name)
  classes_array = ApplicationRecord.subclasses.collect(&:name)
  # => ["User", "Article"] - returns all models names
  
  get_index = classes_array.index(class_name)
  # => 1
  
  req_class = Object.const_get classes_array[get_index]
  # => Article Class
  
  req_class.send(send_name)
  # => Runs Article.new
end
```

Comment: @Ninh Le's answer is the simplest